# Creating a "glossary" of words for text files in a directory

Tags: linux, windows

Want some advice ... Trying to build an index or glossary of words for all text files
in a directory.

It needs to contain the word (special chars removed), followed by names of files for
EVERY occurrence.

I've started to use dictionaries, but do I add the references? 
Some problem for a list of words approach?

Comment: What language are you using? what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary sounds like the way to go.  Every word is a key, the value is the list of text files that hold this word.

A list is much slower then a dictionary if you are searching for a single occurance of a word.  Especially since there will likely be a lot of words in your glossary, I would stick with a dictionary for speed.

Comment: How to build and append (also I would want a total count) references for eachw ord?

Comment: What language are you using?